# VBA: Why Open For Random statement fails?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I have a simple function that access randomly a file and reads a 4 bytes, at a specified position.

The code I am using to pick the record are:

```vb
    Open "C:\MyFile.bin" For Random Access Read As #file_nr Len = 4
    rec_position = 23         '(this is an example)
    Get #file_nr, rec_position, buff
    Close #file_nr
```

where variable "buff" is declared in this way:

```vb
    Dim buff(0 To 3) As Byte   'fixed size array declaration
and it works fine.
```

However... if I want to generalize not for a fixed 4 byte record length but with a record length of "rec_len" bytes I declare "buff" variable in this way:

```vb
    Dim rec_len As Long       'length of the record, in bytes
    Dim buff() As Byte        'dynamic declaration of array to store one record
    ...(omissis)...
    ReDim buff(0 To rec_len - 1)
```

Now the program sticks at "get" instruction and gives me this error:
Runtime error 7 "out of memory".

However I have plenty of free memory, the code is very short, I use a very small rec_len (rec_len=4), I have restarted my PC leaving only what is necessary but the error persists!

Why does this fail when I try to dynamically define the variable "buff" but when it is fixed-size defined (i.e. Dim buff(0 to 3) as Byte) it works perfectly?

Comment: Did your `...(omissis)...` code give a `Long` value to `rec_len` variable? I mean, prior to `ReDim` code line...

Comment: Do you really want to read *records* or just chunks of bytes?

Comment: To FaneDuru: yes my ...(omissis)... code does give a Long value to rec_len variable, is there anything wrong with it? Otherwise I cannot give a value to it.

Comment: To Fun Thomas: I miss the difference, I need to read rec_len consecutive bytes of hte binary file, which for my application  constitutes a record, chunk of bytes, or whatever name you give to it. Of course the first byte read has to be a multiple of rec_len.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the next code explain the way of using `Redim`? Does it return an error, too?

```
Sub testReadBynReDimArray()
 Dim rec_position As Long, buff() As Byte, rec_len As Long
 rec_len = 5   'choose here what value you need. Even if it will be grater than the whole string, the array will be loaded with 0 bytes for the exceeding elements 
 ReDim buff(0 To rec_len)

 rec_position = 23         '(this is an example)
 Open "C:\MyFile.bin" For Binary Access Read As #1
    Get #1, rec_position, buff
 Close #1

 Debug.Print buff(0), buff(1), buff(2), buff(3), buff(4)
End Sub
```